# How can I create a type with keys from union type and different value types?

Tags: typescript

I have this union type:

```
type MyUnion = 'item1' | 'item2';
```

I have also different item types:

```
type Item1Type = {a: 4, b: 5};
type Item2Type = {c: 6, d: 7};
```

I want to define a new type called `MyRecord` that has the following structure:

```
type MyRecord = {'item1': Item1Type, 'item2': Item2Type};
```

But I want to do that with typescript understanding that I refer to `MyUnion` values. So that when I define `MyRecord`, if I enter by mistake `'item3'` I'll have an error.
How can I do that?

Comment: so if I understand correctly, you want to constrain the keys of MyRecord to only 'item1' or 'item2' such that `type MyRecord = {'item1': Item1Type, 'item2': Item2Type, 'item3': any};` yields an error? Or do you mean you want `const myRecord: MyRecord = {'item1': ..., 'item2': ..., 'item3': ...}` to yield an error?

Comment: Why not do the opposite and define your `MyUnion` type as `keyof MyRecord`?

Comment: @PatrickMichaelsen The first option.

Comment: @pink I think you're right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish exactly, but from what it sounds  like, you're looking for something like this:

```
type MyUnion = 'item1' | 'item2';

type Item1Type = {a: 4, b: 5};
type Item2Type = {c: 6, d: 7};
type Item = Item1Type | Item2Type;

const Test: Record<MyUnion, Item> = {
  item1: {
    a: 4,
    b: 5
  },
  item2: {
    a: 4,
    b: 5
  }
  // error  Object literal may only specify known
  // properties, but 'item3' does not exist in
  // type 'Record<MyUnion, Item>'.
  item3: {}
}
```

Or why not just:

```
type Item1ContainerType = { item1: {a: 4, b: 5} };
type Item2ContainerType = { item2: {c: 6, d: 7} };

type MyRecord = Item1ContainerType & Item2ContainerType
type MyUnion = keyof MyRecord;
```

Comment: You're right. I was looking at one possiblr implementation, but creating the union form the types is the right way to do that.